# Select from the drop-down populating 2nd category

Tags: select, asp-classic

I have one table called `tbl_Teacher` with data as:

```
Teacher_ID   Lastname   Firstname   Department
1               aaa         Joe         Math
2               bbb         Jenny       History
3               ccc         Mark        Math
```

I created an ASP `SELECT`.  If I select "aaa, Mark" from drop-down list, then "Match" will be automatically selected on the second drop-down list.  However, it does not take any value after I select the Last and Firstname; it shows No department found.

What did I do wrong? can anyone help?

Thanks very much.

Here is the code:

```vbs
<%  Set rsSelect = Server.CreateObject("adodb.recordset")
    strSQL = "SELECT Lastname, Firstname, Teacher_ID FROM tbl_Teacher;"
    rsSelect.Open strSQL, strCon
    Dim strID
    strID = Request.QueryString("Teacher_ID")
    if not rsSelect.eof then %>
        <select name="Name" onChange="this.form.action='Teacher.asp';this.form.submit();">
             <option value="1">Select a Teacher</option>
             <% do until rsSelect.eof %>
                <option value="<%= rsSelect(0) %>" <% if trim(request.Form("Name")) = trim(rsSelect(0)) then response.write " selected "end if %>><%= rsSelect("Lastname") %>, <%= rsSelect("Firstname") %></option>
                <%  rsSelect.MoveNext
             loop       %>
         </select>
         <% end if 

    if trim(request.Form("Name")) <> "" then
        strSQL = "SELECT Department FROM tbl_Teacher WHERE Teacher_ID = '" & Request.Form("strID") & "';"
        Set rsSelect = Server.CreateObject("adodb.RecordSet")
        rsSelect.Open strSQL, strCon
        if not rsSelect.eof then %>
            <select name="Department">
                <% do until rsSelect.eof       %>
                    <option value="<%= rsSelect("Department") %>"><%= rsSelect("Department") %></option>
                    <% rsSelect.MoveNext
                loop %>
            </select>
            <% else %>
                <i>No Department found</i>
            <%  end if
        else
            response.write "<i>Select a Department</i>"
        end if %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd be far better off utilising the `teacher_id` than a name or code:

```vbs
<%Set rsSelect = Server.CreateObject("adodb.recordset")
strSQL = "SELECT Teacher_ID, Lastname, Firstname FROM tbl_Teacher;"
rsSelect.Open strSQL, strCon, 1, 1
Dim strID
strID = Request.QueryString("Teacher_ID")
if not rsSelect.eof then %>
    <select name="Name" onChange="this.form.action='Teacher.asp';this.form.submit();">
         <option value="1">Select a Teacher</option>
         <% do until rsSelect.eof %>
            <option value="<%= rsSelect(0) %>" <% if request.Form("teacherId") = rsSelect(0) then response.write " selected "end if %>><%= rsSelect("Lastname") %>, <%= rsSelect("Firstname") %></option>
            <%  rsSelect.MoveNext
         loop       %>
     </select>
     <% end if
```

You do have another problem in the following piece of code, however, based around what you are recovering from the database. I would recommend rethinking your design, as you're confusing yourself here and opening up your code to a multitude of errors later on. Try separating your `Departments` into a succinct list of values in its own table; this will prevent anyone from entering unwanted or badly spelled departments later on. You'd then need the following to replace what you have...

```vbs
if request.Form("teacherId")) <> "" then
    Set rsSelect = Server.CreateObject("adodb.RecordSet")
    strSQL = _
        "SELECT " & _ 
            "tbl_department.departmentId, " & _ 
            "tbl_department.departmentName, " & _ 
            "tbl_teacher.department " & _ 
        "FROM " & _ 
            "tbl_departments " & _ 
            "LEFT JOIN " & _ 
            "tbl_teacher " & _ 
                "ON  tbl_departments.departmentId = tbl_teacher.department AND " & _ 
                    "tbl_teacher.teacherId = " & request.Form("teacherId")
    rsSelect.Open strSQL, strCon
    if not rsSelect.eof then %>
        <select name="Department">
            <% do until rsSelect.eof       %>
                <option <%if rsSelect("department")&""<>"" then response.write(" selected ")%> value="<%= rsSelect("Department") %>"><%= rsSelect("Department") %></option>
                <% rsSelect.MoveNext
            loop %>
        </select>
        <% else %>
            <em>No Department found</em>
        <% end if
    else %>
        <em>Select a Department</em>
    <% end if %>
```

**HOWEVER...** There is quite a problem with SQL safety here - the code above leaves you wide open to [SQL injection attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), and should be considered carefully.

Comment: It worked like charm. It is intranet so no worry about SQL injection attacks. Thanks so much.

Comment: There is only one issue. The "selected" is not selected when the second drop-down populates. For example, when I select "aaa, Joe", then the "Math" department selects on the second select. However, "Select a Department" shows up on the first Select, instead of "aaa, Joe". How do I change it to keep the selected value after the second select populates? Thanks.

Comment: @JennyTran: Do you mean when the first `select` populates? If so then this is far more complicated and involves JavaScript...

Comment: I mean AFTER the second SELECT populates. The first SELECT should keep the value that I selected previously.

Comment: I figured it out. I added Trim(request.Form("teacherId")) and it worked. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, @JennyTran - got a bit busy yesterday. Nice - glad you figured the last bit out there. I would consider setting your values to be numbers in the first instance, rather than strings. You can do this using a combination of [`IsNumeric`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176975.aspx#EFAA) and [`CInt`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176975.aspx#ECAA) (or [`CLng`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee156810.aspx) should the need arise). If my answer worked for you, would you mind ticking it as correct, please?